# Link within the same page, leaving history

Tags: html, back-button, browser-history

I have a link `<a href=...>` that points to an anchor on the same page with an id, using `#`. After traversing with that link, when I go through browser history using backward/forward button on the browser, the browser does not scroll the page to the anchored position. Can I let it scroll?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can, using JavaScript. In the script, write this:

```
window.onhashchange = function(){
  location.href = location.hash;
};
```